# Resume SCP download when using .pem file with rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

I have a large file to down form a ssh server, however the connection keeps cutting out. I know that rsync can be used to resume the download however I can not find how to do this when I am using a .pem file.

So my current download command is:

```
scp -i repo.pem user@00.00.00.00:/home/user/file.img .
```

how would I intergrate this with rsync?

Answer (score 0):

Some articles touching on this issue:

- https://community.hpcloud.com/article/using-rsync-upload-or-transfer-files-linux-and-mac-osx
- http://www.anthonychambers.co.uk/blog/rsync-to-aws-ec2-using-.pem-key/9
- http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/backup/rsync-server-to-local-using-ssh-and-pem-key
- http://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync

Basically, supply a custom `ssh` command to `rsync` using `-e`, i.e. something along these lines:

```
rsync -ave "ssh -i my.pem" user@server:/path/to/file .
```